# trying to extend ActiveRecord::Base's save method, but I get "class or module required" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, extends

Here is my AR Model:

```
class MyObject < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ContentSyntax # where parse_out_variables is defined
  serialize :variables
  def save
    self.variables = ContentSyntax.parse_out_variables(self.body)
    super
  end
end
```

now, in my app, I do 
my_object.update_attributes(params)

which worked fine before I tried to extend save.

The Error I get is this:

```
TypeError (class or module required):
  app/models/my_object.rb:64:in `save'
```

But I want this code to execute every time the object is saved. (Or if just one attribute (the 'body') is changed, that would be better)

What is the right way to do this?

EDIT:

using a before_save callback:

```
  before_save {
    self.variables = ContentSyntax.parse_out_variables(self.body)
  }
```

I now have the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `body' for #<Class:0x10a0866b8>):
```

but... it exists!

Comment: Have you considered using the ActiveRecord callbacks (e.g. before_save) to implement this rather than overriding save?

Comment: I have not, I'm looking into that now. first attempt: just changing the method name to `before_save` didn't work -- same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `before_save` callback is the right way to do this. However, when you use a block with an ActiveRecord callback, [the object in question is passed to the block as an argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) so you'd want something more like this:

```
before_save { |o| o.variables = o.parse_out_variables(o.body) }
```

or maybe this:

```
before_save :add_variables

private

def add_variables
    self.variables = parse_out_variables(self.body)
end
```

Comment: hey, I tried   before_save {|o| o.variables = ContentSyntax.parse_out_variables(o.body)}  and I still get class or module required. =\   OH, I changed the methods in ContentSyntax to be static as to help code readability

Comment: this could be a problem with the module I made. though it worked in script/console. So, I don't know why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Does `parse_out_variables` come out as an instance or class method? Does the `before_save :add_variables` version work?

Comment: neither version works. but parse_out_variables is defined in ContentSyntax like this def self.parse_out_variables(text) . so, I think that's a class / static method.

Comment: @TheLindyHop: Change that to `def parse_out_variables(text)` in `ContentSyntax` and you should be good. Otherwise the `include` will be pointless and you'll have to say `ContentSyntax.parse_out_variables(o.body)`.

Comment: still doesn't work. This is so confusing. I do teh include. I call parse_out_variables(..) which is defined as def parse_out_variables in app_root/lib/content_syntax.rb -- which defines Module ContentSyntax.... =(

Comment: I found the problem: I had serialze :variables, :variable_data... and serialize can't do multiple attributes. So I had to split it up into two serialize calls. Since your answer solves my syntax problem initially stated in my question, i'll accept your answer! =D